# Program to guess the number in java using class

Tags: java, class, object, infinite-loop

We are meant to to create a program in java in which the computer randomly guesses a number between 1-10 and allows the user to guess to the number. This is what I have so far, when I execute in cmd i am getting error as follows:

1.) In line number 17 : illegal start of expression

2.) In line number 17 : cannot find symbol

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
class NumberGuess{
        Random r = new Random();
        final int upperbound = 10;
        int random = r.nextInt(upperbound);
        int inputnum;
        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NumberGuess whileloop = new NumberGuess();
          System.out.println("You have to guess the number");
          System.out.println("----------------------------");
          System.out.println("Hint: Number is less than 10");
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        Getter getinput = new Getter();   
        while(whileloop.inptnum != whileloop.random){
        Getter.takeUserInput();
        Getter.isCorrectNumber();
        }
    }
}
class Getter{

   static void takeUserInput(){
    NumberGuess forinput = new NumberGuess();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter your guess:");
    forinput.inputnum = sc.nextInt();
 }

   static void isCorrectNumber(){
   NumberGuess forcompare = new NumberGuess();
   System.out.println(forcompare.random);
   Getter takeinp = new Getter();   
    if(forcompare.inputnum == forcompare.random){
       System.out.println("The guess is correct");
   }
    else{
        System.out.println("The guess is incorrect try again");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Some tips: as you can see, your code doesn't look properly formatted in your question. Format your code by highlighting it and pressing the `{}` button above the text box. Give your variables meaningful names; if you name them obj1, obj2, a, b, etc. we can't follow your logic and yet you expect us to give you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

U can not create a new object in class getter. U must send the creating object.

```
Getter.takeUserInput(obj6)
Getter.isCorrectNumber(obj6);

static void takeUserInput(NumberGuess obj6){

Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter your guess:");
obj6.b = sc.nextInt();
}
static void isCorrectNumber(NumberGuess obj4){
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your class NumberGuess you have the attribute inputnum, but at line 17 (while) you trying to access the attribute "inptnum", which is not exist. :D

**Update:**

Here is the fixed code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

class NumberGuess{
    Random r = new Random();
    final int upperbound = 10;
    int random = r.nextInt(upperbound);
    int inputnum;
        
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        NumberGuess whileloop = new NumberGuess();
        System.out.println("You have to guess the number");
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        System.out.println("Hint: Number is less than 10");
        System.out.println("----------------------------");
        Getter getinput = new Getter();   
        while(whileloop.inputnum != whileloop.random){
           Getter.takeUserInput();
           Getter.isCorrectNumber();
        }
    }
}

class Getter{
   
   static void takeUserInput(){
      NumberGuess forinput = new NumberGuess();
      Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.println("Enter your guess:");
      forinput.inputnum = sc.nextInt();
   }

   static void isCorrectNumber(){
      NumberGuess forcompare = new NumberGuess();
      System.out.println(forcompare.random);
      Getter takeinp = new Getter();   
      if(forcompare.inputnum == forcompare.random){
         System.out.println("The guess is correct");
      }
      else {
         System.out.println("The guess is incorrect try again");
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: can you do the necessary change in the code

Comment: Thank you for updating it can you tell me what line did you change and what changes did you make

Comment: I just fix the attribute name on line 17: from inptnum to inputnum.